# Return list of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an API method that can accept multiple arguments, but those arguments have to be arrays.  What I don't want to do is call each api.someMethod() for each array - I'm trying to lump them together in one call.

For example:

```
function getArrays() {
    var arr1 = ['1','2','3'];
    var arr2 = ['4','5','6'];
    var arr3 = ['7','8'];

    return [ arr1, arr2, arr3 ]
}
```

I apologize for the lack of clarity.  I'm calling:

```
api.someMethod( getArrays() )
```

What happens is that my return wraps my arrays in an array, which won't be accepted as the 'someMethod' is expecting a list of comma separated arrays.

```
api.someMethod( arr1, arr2, arr3 );
```

Comment: How about returning an object which has the 3 arrays as properties? Like: `var x= { arr1: arr1, arr2: arr2, arr3: arr3 }; return x;`

Comment: If you are already using underscore you might use `._union(arr1, arr2);` http://underscorejs.org/#union

Comment: it's is unclear what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) instead of `call`. Then you can pass an array of arguments instead of having to make each argument a separate argument.

```
api.apply(context, [[arr1], [arr2], [arr3]]);
```

Edit in response to updated question.

This is the approach to take:

Use `api` as the context (which it would be if you called the method directly).

```
api.someMethod.apply( api, getArrays() );
```

Comment: Not sure the OP really means `call`, looks like a placeholder for `.arbitraryMethod`.

Comment: @bfavaretto — You could be right. The question is coached in rather ambiguous and abstract terms.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity, I've edited my original question.

Comment: Turns out you were right, Quentin! @hybrid9 This is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Updated the answer with a more specific example.

Comment: @Quentin - this is exactly what i'm looking for.  Now to go figure out why exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't want to do is call each api.call for every array - I'm
>   trying to lump them together in one call.

A function with a variable amount of arguments can be handled in the following manner:

```
function variableArgs(){
  console.log(arguments.length);
  for(var i =0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}
variableArgs("hello")
variableArgs("hello","there","how","are","you");
```

As for returning a single array (if that's what you want) you can:

```
function variableArgs(){
  var ret=[];
  for(var i =0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    console.log("ret is:",ret);
    //processing
    ret=ret.concat(arguments[i]);
  }
  return ret;
}
console.log("result of variableArgs is:",variableArgs([1,2],[3,4],[5,6]))
```